# Authentic Q'laph for Tephilin

Tags: tefilin, mesorah-tradition, safrus, yemenite-temani, klaf-parchment

The Gemara describes a process for developing *q'laph* for *tephilin*. However, this tradition has been lost since then. Has there been any research on restoring the method of producing authentic *q'laph*? What are some important considerations in restoring the processing method? (Apparently, the Habbani Yemenites have a tradition, and if anyone has sources describing it, please post!)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! It would be helpful if you could edit into your question your sources (what gemara, how do you know the tradition was lost, how do you know about the Yemenite tradition, etc).

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Shmuel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: if you're talking about tanning the hide with gallnuts instead of liming it, i'm not sure what you are seeking from us since such hides, while rare, are still available on the market